Problem with level of detail expression (LOD)
I have a table called Patients in tableau that has the following fields



Patients




phone


name


sex


Parsed age


email


patient



Patient is the primary field and is the unique identified. The use case I'm working with is that many patients can share the same phone and email
Parsed Age either returns a numeric value or 0 (if null or negative) so it will not return null at any point.
I only want to pull out patient data (as a single record), filtering out the rest, that meets the following criteria:

If there are multiple patients sharing the same phone
If all the Parsed Age are < 20, take the oldest patient
If all the Parsed Age are > 65, take the youngest patient
Else take the oldest patient that is <= 65 years old

I would like to start first by only showing the patient names that meet the following criteria, lets call this field NameN
I'm using LOD expressions using the following formula for NameN:
{FIXED [phone]:
    // Handle the case when all ages are greater than 65
    IF MIN([Parsed Age]) > 65 THEN 
        // If the minimum age is greater than 65, take the youngest record and return [Name]
        STR(MIN(IF [Parsed Age] = {FIXED [phone]: MIN([Parsed Age])} AND [Parsed Age] > 0 THEN [Name] END))
    // Handle the case when all ages are less than 20
    ELSEIF MAX([Parsed Age]) < 20 THEN 
        // If the maximum age is less than 20, take the oldest record and return [Name]
        STR(MAX(IF [Parsed Age] = {FIXED [phone]: MAX([Parsed Age])} AND [Parsed Age] > 0 THEN [Name] END))
    ELSE
        // Otherwise, take the oldest record with [Age] between 20 and 65 inclusive
        // If no valid patient exists in this range, fall back to returning the oldest overall patient
        STR(
            IFNULL(
                MIN(IF [Parsed Age] = {FIXED [phone]: MAX([Parsed Age])} 
                        AND [Parsed Age] <= 65 
                        AND [Parsed Age] >= 20 THEN [Name] END),
                MIN(IF [Parsed Age] = {FIXED [phone]: MIN([Parsed Age])} AND [Parsed Age] > 0 THEN [Name] END)
            )
        )
    END
}

For most of the cases (around 95-98%) it was able to show the correct data
However, there are still around 1.6k records that are showing as Null
Is there any changes in the code that i need to make such that the Null values are reflecting as the proper patient names correctly?
Also - if the formula works properly - how do I then extend the formula such that there is an additional clause:

If all the Parsed Age are < 20, take the oldest patient
If all the Parsed Age are > 65, take the youngest patient
Else take the oldest patient that is >20 and <= 65 years old whose Parsed Gender = Female
If none exist take the oldest male patient that is >20 and <=65 years old
If none exist in that age range -> take the oldest patient <= 65 years old


Removed the image of code and input as text instead
